# "(" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ";"

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have got the following table:
[image]

I want to pivot this table with code:

```
SELECT productLine, productScale, buyPrice 
FROM PRODUCTS
PIVOT (
        AVG(buyPrice)
        FOR productScale
        IN ('1:10', '1:18')
);
```

But at line 3 of the query, I get an error in the title of this question.
What is wrong?

Comment: PIVOT is not available in mysql, search mysql pivot for alternatives,

Comment: @P.Salmon, thanks, didn't note before.